# can't read jpeg image in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jpeg

I just follow a Tensorflow tutorial and tested the inception3 with 1 image on MacOS (I am using python 3.6.4 and Pycharm). Here is the section where error is reported.

```
......

with tf.gfile.FastGFile('inception_model/classify_image_graph_def.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name = '')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
    #tranverse the directory
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('images/'):
        for file in files:
            #load the image
            image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(root, file), 'rb').read()
            predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' : image_data})
......
```

Here is the reported error:

```
 /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /Users/wenbojiang/PycharmProjects/inception_download/inference.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
2018-01-23 20:19:19.271389: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-01-23 20:19:21.075744: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:334] Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\000\000\000\001Bud1\000\000\020\000\000\000\010\000'
     [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_DecodeJpeg/contents_0_0)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wenbojiang/PycharmProjects/inception_download/inference.py", line 58, in <module>
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' : image_data})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\000\000\000\001Bud1\000\000\020\000\000\000\010\000'
     [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_DecodeJpeg/contents_0_0)]]

Caused by op 'DecodeJpeg', defined at:
  File "/Users/wenbojiang/PycharmProjects/inception_download/inference.py", line 49, in <module>
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name = '')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 313, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\000\000\000\001Bud1\000\000\020\000\000\000\010\000'
     [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_DecodeJpeg/contents_0_0)]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The image I used is for sure a Jpeg format. Does anyone know what's the problem here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're looping over `files in os.walk('images/')` ...are you sure all the files in there are Jpeg images?  Trying logging the current filename - maybe there's another file in there, hidden file or something.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Looks like there is a hidden file in my folder but I can't see it even with 'ls' command

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the hexes printed by Tensorflow,

```
\000\000\000\001Bud1\000\000\020\000\000\000\010\000
```

it looks like it's trying to read a .DS_Store file (http://filext.com/file-extension/DS_STORE).

Make sure you're not reading those :)

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('images/'):
    for file in files:
        if not file.endswith('.jpg') or file.startswith('.'):
             continue  # Skip!
        # ... read ...
```

Comment: This advice resolved my problem! Thanks! So There's a hidden file in my folder? But the image is the only file I can see with 'ls' command.

Comment: Try `ls -la`. Dotfiles are hidden by default.